# how to prevent PowerShell adding \ to a string

Tags: json, powershell

I'm currently working with Powershell editing JSONs

My JSON looks like this:

```
   {
        "value":  ["E_"]
   }
```

I only want to add a specific number after `E_`.
The result should look like this:

```
{
"value": ["E_5"]
}
```

My PS Script:

```
$tdePath = 'C:\temp\tde.csv'

$dirName = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDir -Filter TDE_Config.json -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select-Object DirectoryName | Export-Csv $tdePath  -NoTypeInformation 



$importTDEJson = Import-Csv $tdePath -Encoding UTF8 | % {

[String]$nr = $_.DirectoryName.Split('\')[6].split(' ')[4] 

$full_path = $_.DirectoryName + "\TDE_Config.json"


[int]$nr2 = $nr -as [int] #Convert String to Int to convert 004 -> 4

$a = Get-Content $full_path -raw | ConvertFrom-Json




$a.value= "[`"E_" + $nr2 + "`"]" 
$a | ConvertTo-Json  | set-content $full_path -Force

}
```

Only excuting `` "[`"E_" + $nr2 + "`"]" `` returns the value I need.
For example if `$nr2 = 145` it returns in ps console

```
["E_145"]
```

But my JSON looks like this:

```
{
"value": "[\"E_145\"]"
}
```

Why is powershell adding \ to my string?
How can I prevent powershell adding \ to my string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing Json by hand and Json by `ConvertTo-Json`. 
Powershell is doing javascript escaping of the backslashes you insert. Just set `$a.value` like this:

```
$a.value= @("E_$nr2")
```

That will create an array and the Json conversion will do the rest for you.

EDIT:
Here is a proof of concept:

```bsh
$a = [pscustomobject]@{
   value = 'Something else'
}
$nr2 = 145
$a.value= @("E_$nr2") 
$a | ConvertTo-Json
```

outputs:

```
{
    "value":  [
                  "E_145"
              ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I add those brackets?
JSON should look like this:
Example:
`$nr2 = 145`

JSON:

`{
"value": ["E_145"]
}`

Comment: ConvertTo-Json should do that for you if value is an array, there is no need to do it yourself.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added a piece of code that shows that it works.